# Regular expression issue when validating '/' character

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have been having some problems with regular expressions. I want to validate user input when a bus number is entered.

Examples: 37, 37A, 37S, 37A/L, 16A/250, 16A/250K etc

The regular expression I came up with is

```
(^\d{1,3}[A-Z]{0,3})|(^[\d{1,3}[A-Z]{0,3}\/\d{0,3}[A-Z]{0,3}])
```

It validates 37, 37A, 37S but when it comes to validating 37A/L it fails. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong with this?

Note:I am using a regular expression validator for a text box. I have placed this in the ValidationExpression.

Comment: Most likely that since you are specifying an 'OR' that the first part of the regex is being matched and the second discarded - also you have an extra square bracket at the end

Comment: Is this only in C# @Nolonar? Because in other languages I of know you have to escape a forward-slash.

Comment: @Simon Sorry, my bad. I used `"\/"` instead of `@"\/"`. That's why my debugger complained. I just tested it with `@"\/"` and it does work. I deleted my previous comment. In C# you don't need to escape the forward slash though (but it's still valid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was having problem as end of string was not specified.

Replace with this,

```
(^\d{1,3}[A-Z]{0,3}$)|(^\d{1,3}[A-Z]{0,3}\/\d{0,3}[A-Z]{0,3}$)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to escape the `/` character, try the following:

```
(^\d{1,3}[A-Z]{0,3}(?:/\d{0,3}[A-Z]{0,3})?)
```

You can additionally enforce that the entire line matches the regex by specifying the EOS character:

```
(^\d{1,3}[A-Z]{0,3}(?:/\d{0,3}[A-Z]{0,3})?$)
```

NB as @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing points out in the comments the parenthesis around the entire regex are unnecessary:

```
^\d{1,3}[A-Z]{0,3}(?:/\d{0,3}[A-Z]{0,3})?$
```

Comment: +1 This one makes more sense to me, since the second part after slash seems optional.

Comment: BTW, why do you keep the parentheses enclosing the whole expression?

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing Just in case the OP was referencing the second group eg `groups[1]`. It is of course redundant - I've updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^(\d{1,3}[A-Z]{0,3})(\/\d{0,3}[A-Z]{0,3})?$
```